# Min/max values of a templated type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a rather basic question. Suppose I have a templated function:

```
bool is_max(std::uint32_t val) {
  return (val == std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
}
```

However, to make my function flexible, I'd like to use templates:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_max(T val) {
  return (val == ???);
}
```

The std::numeric_limits function would work with built-in types, but obviously doesn't work for user-defined types.

Is there some standard operator or function that the current built-in and most numeric types (I'm trying to use [cnl::fixed_point](https://github.com/johnmcfarlane/cnl)) that can be used here to find min/max value?

Comment: You are allowed to create specializations of `std::numeric_limits` for your own types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to handle this is to continue using `std::numeric_limits`, and add template specializations for all of the desired input types.

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

> Implementations may provide specializations of `std::numeric_limits` for implementation-specific types: e.g. GCC provides `std::numeric_limits<__int128>`. Non-standard libraries may add specializations for library-provided types, e.g. OpenEXR provides `std::numeric_limits<half>` for a 16-bit floating-point type.